# Where to grab Cloudflare "X-Auth-Key" from?

Tags: cloudflare

I am looking at the [Cloudflare API](https://api.cloudflare.com/#getting-started-resource-ids) to grab a list of domains in our Cloudflare account.

Where do I grab the Cloudflare "X-Auth-Key" from so I can run the following command:

```
curl.exe -X GET "https://api.cloudflare.com/client/v4/zones" -H "X-Auth-Email: xx@xx.com" -H "X-Auth-Key: xxx" -H "Content-Type: application/json";
```

Thanks,
Steve

Answer (score 1):

In order to get a key provided to **X-Auth-Key** you need to register [here](https://dash.cloudflare.com/sign-up)

Once registered, go to **My profile** -> [API Tokens tab](https://dash.cloudflare.com/profile/api-tokens), there you will be able to generate a key using **Create token** button.

Comment: Thanks. I have a token, but see no `X-Auth-Key`.

Answer (score 1):

Go to **Your profile** -> **Overview** -> **[Get your API token](https://dash.cloudflare.com/profile/api-tokens)** -> **Global API Key**

Now click on **view** button and copy the `X-Auth-Key`

I use this code to Purge everything using Cloudflare **X-Auth-Key**

```cs
[HttpPost]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Purge()
        {
            try
            {
                string zone_id = "****cd149***";
                string url = "https://api.cloudflare.com/client/v4/zones/" + zone_id + "/purge_cache";
                string x_auth_email = "yourEmail@gm.com";
                string x_auth_key = "***51d01***"; // Global API Key

                using (var client = new HttpClient())
                {
                    using (var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, url))
                    {
                        request.Headers.Add("X-Auth-Email", x_auth_email);
                        request.Headers.Add("X-Auth-Key", x_auth_key);
                        var content = new StringContent("{\n\"purge_everything\":true\n}", null, "application/json");
                        request.Content = content;
                        var response = await client.SendAsync(request);
                        response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
                        return Ok();
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                return BadRequest("An unexpected error occurred\r\nMake sure to enter your data correctly: Settings > Cloudflare");
            }
        }
```